# Dagger 2 + MVP - single presenter assigned to multiple fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger, android-mvp

I would like to implement a part of an application that takes some steps that would be handled by one presenter. I have declared one scope:

```
@Scope
annotation class FormScope
```

next, I wanted to declare a module that would provide necessary dependencies:

```
    @Module
object FormModule {

    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    fun providesFragmentManager(activity: FragmentActivity): FragmentManager = activity.supportFragmentManager

    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    fun providesNavigation(fragmentManager: FragmentManager): SobergridCoachingNavigationUnauthorizedFirstStep = SobergridCoachingNavigationUnauthorizedFirstStep(fragmentManager)

    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    fun providesCoordinator(navigation: NavigationUnauthorized): CoordinatoUnauthorized = CoordinatoUnauthorized(navigation)

    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    @Reusable
    fun providesPresenter(coordinator: CoordinatoUnauthorized): OnboardingFragmentContract.Presenter = FormPresenter(coordinator)

}
```

and finally, I bind the modules into fragments that I want inject dependencies into:

```
@Module(includes = [AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class])
abstract class FragmentBindingModule {

    @FormScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [FormFirstModule::class, FormModule::class])
    abstract fun contributesFormFirst(): FormFirstFragment
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [FormSecondModule::class, FormModule::class])
    abstract fun contributesFormSecond(): FormSecondFragment
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [FormThirdModule::class, FormModule::class])
    abstract fun contributesFormThird(): FormThirdFragment
}
```

The problem that I encounter is that every single time a new fragment is showed the Dagger creates a new instance of the Presenter. I want to use a single presenter for all of those Fragments. What I do wrong? What should I improve to be able to achieve my goal?

**UPDATE**

I have also tried annotating my provide method with `@Singleton`

```
    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    @Signleton
    fun providesPresenter(coordinator: CoordinatoUnauthorized): OnboardingFragmentContract.Presenter = FormPresenter(coordinator)
```

but this leads to the compilation error. The last thing that I tried was to put annotations (both `@Reusable` and `@Singleton`) before the declaration of the Presenter class. This approach gives me no compilation errors but still, there is more than one instance of the Presenter class.

Comment: All fragments are in the same Activity ?

Comment: @eurosecom yes all of the fragments are in the same activity

Answer (score 1):

Move your Presenter provides to FragmentActivity Module with Scope to get the same Presenter for all fragments in Activity

```
@Module
public class FragmentActivityModule {

    //common provides for all fragments
    @Provides
    @FormScope
    public YourPresenter providesYourPresenter() {
        return new YourPresenter();
    }

    ....
```

And your builder have to look like this

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBuilder {

@FormScope
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {FragmentActivityModule.class, Form1FragmentProvider.class
        , Form2FragmentProvider.class})
abstract FragmentActivity bindFragmentActivity();
```

In Form1FragmentModule are provides only for Form1Fragment.
Create FragmentProviders for all fragments Form1FragmentProvider, Form2FragmentProvider...

```
@Module
public abstract class Form1FragmentProvider {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = Form1FragmentModule.class)

    abstract Form1Fragment provideForm1FragmentFactory();
}
```

Do not forget implement HasSupportFragmentInjector in your FragmentActivity

```
public class  FragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HasSupportFragmentInjector {

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector;

....

@Override
    public AndroidInjector<Fragment> supportFragmentInjector() {
        return fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
```

Do not forget attach AndroidSupportInjection in your Fragments

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this);
        super.onAttach(context);
    }
```